# GoogleVis Geoplot Toottip Formatting in R

Tags: r, google-visualization, googlevis

I have a simple (2 column) data frame I'm trying to plot with a googleVis Geo Chart.  One column is categorical (state) and the other is continuous (cash).

I'm having trouble formatting cash as cash (e.g, formatted "$100,000" instead of "100000" as is appears in the data frame) both in the legend and in the tooltip display.

I can't seem to find anything on line that address this.  Here is my code:

```
cash = c(100000,200000,175000)
state = c("Arizona","Connecticut","Washington")
data = data.frame(cash,state) 

GeoStates = gvisGeoChart(data, "State", "Cash" ,
                        options=list(region="US", 
                                     displayMode="regions", 
                                     resolution="provinces",
                                     width=600, height=400,
                                     colorAxis ="{minValue: 0,  
                                         colors [#deebf7', '#3182bd']}"))
plot(GeoStates)
```

Can someone help?

Thanks.

Comment: did you try `legend.numberFormat`? -- listed in the [configuration options](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/geochart#configuration-options) -- you may need to [format](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/reference#numberformat) the data for the tooltip

Comment: @WhiteHat.  I'll give that a try.  Problem with formatting the data in the dataframe is if I format it as "$xxx,xxx" in becomes a chr and doesn't render in the figure/tooltip.

Comment: not familiar with `r` -- but in JavaScript you can set both in column value object as `{v: 1234.5, f: '$1,234.50'}`

Comment: I'm getting some guidance from outside stackoverflow - One has to make use of the googleVis API for visualization.  However, the code for the API appears to be html - so its a question of how to do it in r.  Will update this when I get more info.